# RadioGroup inside of a panel?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

How to display a RadioGroup inside of a panel ? I need to display something like this :

[image]

I created the `RadioGroup` and the `RadioButtons` by code, but I don'y know how to display the panel as in the image.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any "panel", just set that `background` for your `RadioGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code into relative layout

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/ratingRadioGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnDob"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50pt"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:background="#F9E60E" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/e"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ratingRadioGroup"
                android:checked="true"
                android:paddingRight="10pt"
                android:text="M" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:text="F" />
        </RadioGroup>
```